# Удаление сообщений или диалогов как в ВК,Фейсбуке и Одноклассниках

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как вот реализуется удаление диалогов или сообщений как в Вк например.В том плане если я удаляю переписку или диалог то у второго пользователя остается вся переписка.Вот например у меня есть такая структура группы.

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
> `message_group` (   `user_one` int(11)
> NOT NULL,   `user_two` int(11) NOT
> NULL,   `hash` int(11) NOT NULL,
> `date_group` datetime NOT NULL )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Я думаю нужно добавить еще два поля каких либо.Например при записи в бд будет отправлять 0, а при удалении делать просто упдейт на 1 типа скрытый и выводить только которое равняется 0.Скажите пожалуйста правильно ли я мыслю вообще?

Comment: > Скажите пожалуйста правильно ли я мыслю вообще?

Не совсем. По-хорошему долна быть отдельная сущность чат, внутри которой хранятся сообщения, а вот к чату уже организован раздельный доступ. И "удаление чата" - это отзыв доступа, если доступ утрачен полностью и участников больше нет, тогда данные удаляются.

Comment: я делал это доп полями, типа del_sender и del_receiver, если оба поля true, то сообщение совсем удаляется. Все отлично работало

Comment: @thunder Да я вот думаю тоже так же вот сделать.А вот как понять если оба true?проверять если оба скрыли типа сообщения то удаляем если нет то оставляем?

Comment: ну тот кто отправил удаяет сообщение, поле del_sender=true, потом получатель удаляет: del_recv=true, дальше можно кроном либо при постановке одного из флагов проверять если оба удалили, то удалить физически, если нет, то только флаг поставить

Comment: @thunder Спасибо